# update Numpy Array element if there is a True in the whole row

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a very large numpy array with True/False that has the shape of `(500000, 36)`,
here I put a sample array for this question:

```
mask_array = [[False, False, False, False .., False],
              [False, True, False, False ..., False]]
```

For each row of the numpy array, I want to check if there is any element that is `True`, and if there is, set the last element of the row equal to `True`.

This is my sample code:

```
def update_array(x):
    if x.any():
       x[-1] == True

np.apply_along_axis(update_array, axis=1, arr=mask)
```

Expected results:

```
mask_array = [[False, False, False, False .., False],
              [False, True, False, False ..., True]]
```

Comment: So whats the question?

Comment: I can't find a way to update the last element if there is one element in the row that is equal to True.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `any` with specified `axis` and then assing result to last elements of array's rows.

Sample code:

```py
mask_array = np.array([[False, False, False, False , False],
                       [False, True, False, False , False]])

mask_array[:,-1] = mask_array.any(axis=1)
```

Result:

```
array([[False, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, False,  True]])
```